# Convert a column inside a dataset from UTC to datetime using pd.to_datetime Python

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, plot

I have a two-column time-series dataset with column 1 representing time in UTC format. I want to show a plot of the data with (hh:mm:ss) in the x axis. Here is my code so far. FIY, I am not receiving error messages when running this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = 'channel_9.dat'
data = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=' ', skiprows=0, dtype=float, max_rows=70000)
#data loaded is of type numpy.ndarray
pd.to_datetime(data[:,1],unit='s')
df= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Time (hr)','Active Power Consumption (W)'])
df.plot(x='Time (hr)',y='Active Power Consumption (W)')
```

Plot of power against time (time is still in UTC format):

[image]

Comment: you don't assign the output of `pd.to_datetime` to anything (it doesn't do the conversion in-place). Use  `df['Time (hr)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time (hr)'], unit='h')` after you created the dataframe.

Comment: Thank you! it worked for me. I only had to change unit from 'h' to 's'